# bind class data to XMLHttpRequest class without removing xhr data

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am using `XMLHttpRequest` inside a class:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        this.checkData(data);
    }
    else{
        console.log(this);
    }
}.bind(this);
```

if i use `bind(this)` at the end i will lose access of `this` for `xhr`, and if i removed it i will lose access of `this` for my class, what should i do?

Comment: Use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)...

Comment: so use xhr.readyState.... xhr.status....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options you have....

You either store this into a variable outside and use it inside and do not use bind.

```
var _this = this;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        _this.checkData(data);
    }
    else{
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

Or you use bind() and use xhr instead of this

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        this.checkData(data);
    }
    else{
        console.log(xhr);
    }
}.bind(this);
```